# Horizontal divs overlapping each other?

Tags: css, html, layout

I have two divs on my page. The first is a header div which contains a logo image and
a search input. The second div is going to contain a horizontal row which all of my navigation
links will be in.

The problem is the second div for some reason sits literally on top of my first div, taking up
all the space between the logo image and the search box?

Here are the two divs

```
    <div id="container">

        <div id="logo">
            <img src="HeaderLogo.jpg" alt="logo">
        </div>

        <div id="searchboxcontainer">
            <form action="search.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="searchterm" id="searchbox">
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" id="searchsubmit">
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div id="navbar">   

    </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
  #logo {

width:30%;
float:left;
margin-left:50px;   
} 

#searchboxcontainer {

background-color:#A3E0FF;
width:30%;
float:right;
margin-right:50px;
margin-top:60px;
padding:15px;
}

#searchsubmit {

background-color:#19A3D1;
}

#navbar {

width:100%;
background-color:#CACABC;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: Pravin Vaichal's solution is what I was thinking of, but without a clear picture about what you are trying to achieve, it's finding a needle in a very small haystack..

Comment: @Tsasken a small haystack?

Comment: @DejaVu Well, it's not a lot of code, is it? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply `#navbar{clear:both }` may solve your problem

sidenote:  if you want parent i.e. #container to cover height of floated divs you may apply `#container{overflow:auto;}`

Please check complete code as follows http://jsfiddle.net/2Mh9y/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle, added

```
border-box and overflow auto
```

deleted some margins, and added some paddings. Not sure if this is what u wanted
http://jsfiddle.net/WSaj8/12/